Weak measurements, non-demolition measurements and interaction-free measurements vs. wave function collapse
Let $\psi \in \mathcal{H}$ be a (pure) state of some physical system and suppose we measure an observable $A$ (represented as self adjoint (say bounded) operator, i.e. an element of  $\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H})$). Let $(e_i)_i$ be a basis of $\mathcal{H}$ consisting from eigenvectors of $A$ and express $\psi=\sum_i c_i e_i$ where $\sum_i |c_i|^2=1$. Then after measuring $A$ on a system in the state $\psi$ we get the corresponding eigenvalue $\lambda_i$ of $A$ with probability $|c_i|^2$ and the state $\psi$ collapses to $e_i$.
Recently I've heard about the so called weak measurements as well about interaction free measurements: I'm not sure how much they are related. Unfortunately I haven't seen how these are modelled mathematically: only some (rather vague) description in words.

How these measurements are modelled mathematically? In particular, what happens with the quantum state after performing these kind of measurements? Does it collapse?

EDIT: since apparently some people decided that this question is too broad let me be a little bit more specific:
I would like to see two examples: one example of a weak measurement and one example of interaction free measurement where it is explicitly stated:

What are the relevant Hilbert spaces
What are the relevant states before measurements
What are the operators corresponding to the observables being measured
What happens with the state after measurements, i.e. what is the effect of a collapse if there is any.

So in a nutshell: I would like to see a similar description which I gave above for ordinary measurements but now in the context of weak and interaction free measurements.
I hope that now the question is clear and detailed enough. If still not then I don't know what else I could do.

Have you digested https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_measurement#Weak_interaction_and_ancilla_coupled_measurement and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elitzur%E2%80%93Vaidman_bomb_tester#How_it_works? They are different concepts in general, although some people try to posit counterfactual properties for states in an interaction-free-measurement setup by using weak measurements

This broad question fills books.

Yes, I have looked at wikipedia but I haven't found an answer for my questions

The equations of motion of quantum theory such as the Schrodinger equation or any of the equations of quantum field theories such as QED don't imply and aren't consistent with wavefunction collapse. Collapse is usually not modelled at all, it is just imposed in an ad hoc manner with no explanation or motivation.
Quantum theory would have to modified to include collapse as in spontaneous collapse theories:
https://arxiv.org/abs/2310.14969
Such theories don't currently reproduce most of the experimentally tested predictions of quantum theory:
https://arxiv.org/abs/2205.00568
Since quantum theory already produces those predictions without collapse there is no reason to postulate collapse.
In quantum experiments the result changes if the evolution of any of the possible states during the experiment changes, see Section 2 of
https://arxiv.org/abs/math/9911150
In quantum physics without collapse a standard measurement is just an interaction that produces a record that can be copied. Such measurements suppress quantum interference: an effect called decoherence
https://arxiv.org/abs/1911.06282
The information in the record is contained in the projectors of the relevant observable. Many measurements including repeated, continuous and unsharp measurements don't fit in with the collapse postulate because of interference effects being relevant in real measurements
https://arxiv.org/abs/1604.05973
Weak measurements are properties of pre-selected and post-selected quantum systems: you select initial $|\psi\rangle$ and final $|\phi\rangle$ states and then define the weak value of an observable as
$A_w=\frac{\langle\psi|A|\phi\rangle}{\langle\psi|\phi\rangle}$
This describes features of the evolution of that observable between measurements
https://arxiv.org/pdf/0706.1348
https://arxiv.org/abs/1703.08870
Weak measurements can have values outside of the standard expectation value as a result of interference effects
https://arxiv.org/abs/1410.0943
Interaction free measurements occur when the outcome of an experiment is affected by one of the possible states being blocked during interference. the interfering system is detected at the end of the experiment so that version of the system wasn't blocked but the lack of the phase contribution from the blocked state still changes the outcome:
https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0103081
There is a discussion of the relationship between weak and interaction free measurements here
https://arxiv.org/abs/1610.07169
An interaction free measurement can be looked on as a post selection experiment so it's not surprising that it is related to weak measurements.

Thank you for a very detailed answer and plenty of references!

@truebaran Looking on Google Scholar tends to produce better results than looking on Wikipedia
